# how bake the diffuse map when in the material I mix principled shader?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking

I do not understand why in the bake of the diffuse I see only a principled shader node and the other (the red one) is completely ignored
[image]
**Nodes:**
[image]

this is the blend file [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nir6eefsudbf4yk/sfera1.blend?dl=0)
tnx in advance

Comment: Your nodes are not visible in the picture.

Comment: ok look this https://www.dropbox.com/s/3sdg1y8oxa1ne5o/screenshot.4918.jpg?dl=0   or download the blend file so you can see it better

Comment: Buddy you have attached the blend file here, I mean to say that the image you attached is not useful, you may try replacing it here.

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not understand what you mean

Comment: It is already working, try dis-connecting Principled(the red one) Shader from the Mix-shader, you will notice the change after connecting and dis-connecting it.

Comment: solved!!!! eliminating all the values or related to the metallic the diffuse bake is perfect !!!

Comment: the only solution is to eliminate the value or map relative to the metallic.  Connecting and dis-connecting does not solve the problem. thanks anyway for trying ;)

Comment: Nice. It would be great if you post your node setup below, so others can see it!